# How to convert array of strings to string column?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to save a JSON to a table in MySQL.

After a bit of reading I found out that the path to load the data into mysql is json->dataframe->mysql.

```
{"name":"Johny","hobbies":["swiming","cooking"]}
{"name":"James","hobbies":["baseketball","fishing"]}
{"name":"Tom","hobbies":["singing","football"]}
```

I read the json file be using below command:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("test.json")
df.show()
df.printSchema()
```

and output:

```
+--------------------+-----+                                                    
|             hobbies| name|
+--------------------+-----+
|  [swiming, cooking]|Johny|
|[baseketball, fis...|James|
| [singing, football]|  Tom|
+--------------------+-----+

root
 |-- hobbies: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

When using below command:

```
df.registerTempTable("mytable")
sqlContext.
  sql("SELECT * FROM mytable").
  write.
  mode(SaveMode.Append).
  jdbc(url,"jsontest",prop)
```

I am getting below error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for array

How can I convert the array of strings to one string like `swiming, cooking` in the DataFrame?

Comment: What Spark version do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the `array` of `string` to a `string` using a simple `udf`

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

 val value = udf((arr: Seq[String]) => arr.mkString(","))

 val newDf = df.withColumn("hobbies", value($"hobbies"))
```

Or you can also use the concat_ws function as as said by Jacek

```
df.withColumn("hobbies", concat_ws(col("hobbies")))
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+-----+                                                    
|             hobbies| name|
+--------------------+-----+
|  swiming, cooking  |Johny|
|baseketball, fishing|James|
| singing, football  |  Tom|
+--------------------+-----+
```

Then save the `newDF` as

```
newDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url,"jsontest",prop)
```

Comment: What's `$"hobbies".mkString`?

Comment: Thanks Shankar Koiralafor you reply.but I get the error.Error:(45, 41) value $ is not a member of StringContext
    val newDF = df.withColumn("hobbies",$"hobbies".mkString)

Comment: Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: I can't build it successfully.

Comment: I import the functions.but I get the error.Error:(47, 48) value $ is not a member of StringContext
    val newDf = df.withColumn("hobbies", value($"hobbies"))

Comment: Later I found concat_ws function is used to convert array<string> to string use this in your case   df.withColumn("hobbies", concat_ws(col("hobbies")))

Answer (score 4):

> How can I convert the array of strings to one string like `swiming, cooking` in the DataFrame?

You should use the built-in [concat_ws](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@concat_ws(sep:String,exprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function.

> **concat_ws(sep: String, exprs: Column*): Column** Concatenates multiple input string columns together into a single string column, using the given separator.

A solution would then be as follows.

```
val hobbies = Seq(
  (Array("swiming","cooking"), "Johny"),
  (Array("baseketball","fishing"), "James"),
  (Array("singing","football"), "Tom")
).toDF("hobbies", "name")

val solution = hobbies.select(concat_ws(",", $"hobbies") as "hobbies", $"name")
scala> solution.show
+-------------------+-----+
|            hobbies| name|
+-------------------+-----+
|    swiming,cooking|Johny|
|baseketball,fishing|James|
|   singing,football|  Tom|
+-------------------+-----+
```